# Deleting an Application from 8830

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

We have developed an application for 8830 Device and its working fine.
The problem that we are facing now is that, we are unable to delete the application from the device.

- We selected the application, pressed the menu button, but dont find any delete option.
- We went to the applications list, through advanced options, but surprisingly we dont see our application in that that applications list(By Deploying the same application in higher devices such as 9630 and 9550,9800) we see a delete option, by pressing menu and also see our application in the options->application list.
- We went to modules, and identified the modules of the application, but there also we were not able to find the delete option in it.
- We also tried using the blackberry desktop software too, but in vain, we dont find our application in that list too

** The current device we are using is not configured with any BES(We are registered with the BIS) And moreover, we are able to delete the yahoo messenger, gtalk, twitter from the mobile except our application(It just behaves like some shortcut).

Do we need to add some extra lines of code in any class so that it gets identified as an application.Kindly help on this.

Thanks in advance,
Dheeraj Jami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when an application installed via BB Desktop Manager + .alx file or wirelessly (Browser + jad file) the application is listed in the applications list and can be deleted by end-user without any problems.

But if the application installed via javaloader or cod file created automatically via RIM SDK then the application won't be listed in the application list.

The working way to delete unwanted cod file(s) is using javaloader.exe that comes with JDE distribution package.

Connect your device to the desktop computer via usb-cable and type the command in command line, when you are in folder where javaloader.exe located:

javaloader -usb erase -f unwantedfile.cod

and press Enter

Comment: Thank you Rafael Osipov. This is exactly what we wanted. Thank you so much. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> Do we need to add some extra lines of code in any class so that it gets identified as an application.

No, you don't. From my experience it just happens sometimes with BlackBerries. In this case the only way to get rid of it is to pull the battery out of the device. This action resets the device to its factory state (all apps installed by user will be lost).

Comment: Yeah we have done that Arhimed but that doesnot help, It still persists.

Comment: During the development stage we are trying to delete the application from the device by using the command "javaloader erase -f abcdefgh.cod"

But, how could a user delete the application if there is no option to delete an application.

If you could provide us the code which would make the application identified as an application :)

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: @Dheeraj Jami: Sorry, it's unclear for me what you are asking for saying "the code which would make the application identified as an application". Probably just open up any sample code that is a part of BB SDK to see an example of an application..